# Partial shade of distribution plot using Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, distribution, seaborn

Following simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
dist = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
ax = sns.kdeplot(dist, shade=True);
```

Yields the following image:

[image]

I would like to only shade everything right (or left to some x value). What is the simplest way? I am ready to use something other than Seaborn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After calling `ax = sns.kdeplot(dist, shade=True)`, the last line in `ax.get_lines()` corresponds to the kde density curve:

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(dist, shade=True)
line = ax.get_lines()[-1]
```

You can extract the data corresponding to that curve using `line.get_data`:

```
x, y = line.get_data()
```

Once you have the data, you can, for instance, shade the region corresponding to `x > 0` by selecting those points and calling `ax.fill_between`:

```
mask = x > 0
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
ax.fill_between(x, y1=y, alpha=0.5, facecolor='red')
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dist = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
ax = sns.kdeplot(dist, shade=True)
line = ax.get_lines()[-1]
x, y = line.get_data()
mask = x > 0
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
ax.fill_between(x, y1=y, alpha=0.5, facecolor='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The Axes class is [documented here](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html). 
It does mention [`get_lines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_lines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_lines), and here is the doc for [`get_data`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html).

Comment: But to be honest, I learn 
these kinds of things mainly from seeing other people's solutions on Stackoverflow, and occasionally by reading the source code. [IPython's tab-completion](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html) is an immense help when you want to discover object attributes and methods.

Answer (score 5):

Using seaborn is often fine for standard plots, but when some customized requirements come into play, falling back to matplotlib is often easier.

So one may first calculate the kernel density estimate and then plot it in the region of interest.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")

dist = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(dist)
# plot complete kde curve as line
pos = np.linspace(dist.min(), dist.max(), 101)
plt.plot(pos, kde(pos))
# plot shaded kde only right of x=0.5
shade = np.linspace(0.5,dist.max(), 101)
plt.fill_between(shade,kde(shade), alpha=0.5)

plt.ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```

[image]