# Plot intersection between y-axis grid and kdeplot on seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created the following plot using seaborn kdeplot and customizing the gridlines.
[image]

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
cdf_accuracy = sns.kdeplot(eval_df['accuracy'], cumulative=True)
cdf_accuracy.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.25))
cdf_accuracy.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
```

However, I would like to show the gridlines on the x-axis just on the points were the y-axis gridlines intersect the plot. There is a way to do this?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Do you want a line or gridline ?? You can turn off x-gridlines and use `ax.axvline()`  method of `axes` .

Comment: I would like to have lines that show the intersection between the gridlines on the y-axis at 25, 50 and 75 and the plotted distribution.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your characteristic is monotonic, which should be given with a cumulative dataset, you could simply use interpolation on the y-values:

```
import numpy as np

y_intrsct = [.25, .5, .75]
x_intrsct = np.interp(y_intrsct, y_data, x_data)
```

which results in

```
array([67.69792378, 83.24194722, 92.24041857])
```

[image]

plotted with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_data, y_data)
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
ax.grid(axis='y')
ax.vlines(x_intrsct, *ax.get_ylim())
```

Comment: Thanks SpghttCd for the answer. However, I am not really sure it would work for me as I have no way to retrieve the y_data. There would be some way to create interpolation directly in the seaborn kdeplot?

Comment: I'm not too experienced with seaborn's kdeplot, but after a short trial I was able to get the data via `cdf_accuracy.get_children()[0].get_data()`

Comment: Since a kdeplot is often used in conjunction with bars as well, it is a bit dangerous to rely on the line being the first child of the axes. So more robust (but still subject to potential failure in more complex plots) would be `ax.lines[0].get_data()`.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I thought that this is not a proper way... Isn't there an alternative function which returns the data officially, which could then perhaps be plotted by a simple `plt.plot()`? Perhaps in `numpy`, `scipy` or `pandas`?

Comment: What about e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html

Comment: Sure, cf. e.g. my answer to this question with the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099765/partial-shade-of-distribution-plot-using-seaborn or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487952/how-to-plot-the-difference-of-two-distributions-in-a-seaborn or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647197/how-to-plot-several-kernel-density-estimates-using-matplotlib